# Hiding "Argument isn't numeric" in a custom sort

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a sort function that looks like this:

```
sub custom_sort {
    my @a_cols = split( /\|/, $a );
    my @b_cols = split( /\|/, $b );

    return $a_cols[0] <=> $b_cols[0]     #numeric compare first column;
        || $a_cols[1] <=> $b_cols[1]     #second column numeric compare
        || $a_cols[1] cmp $b_cols[1];    #alphabetic compare second column
}
```

This works nicely for it's desired purpose - column `1` can either be alphabetic or numeric, and I want to sort these things separately.

There's just one problem - I get warnings if this column isn't just numeric. Whilst I can separate out the comparison and test/return - is there a neater way?

I'm sort of thinking perhaps using `r` regex:

```
$a_cols[1] =~ s/^\D+/0/r
```

Or maybe a ternary operator.

But is there a more elegant way to say "if it's text, treat it as zero"?

```
128114529000000|10|0
1212835|A|0
128114529000000|1|0
1212835|G|0
128114529000000|3|0
1212835|T|0
128114529000000|2|0
1212835|H|0
128114529000000|9|0
```

And desired output is:

```
1212835|A|0
1212835|G|0
1212835|H|0
1212835|T|0
128114529000000|1|0
128114529000000|2|0
128114529000000|3|0
128114529000000|9|0
128114529000000|10|0
```

e.g. sorting based on first key, then second - but comparing alphabetically or numerically depending on context. Vanilla 'alpha' sort doesn't work, because of the `10` in there.

Comment: Could you give some example of these non-numeric values?

Comment: Updated with sample.

Comment: This code will sort a string such as `2A` falsely as the number `2`, while giving the numeric warning. I suppose your data does not have those, but it might be a problem down the line.

Comment: That's acceptable in this context. All the fields I have to work with are either/or.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I notice that you do not pre-process your input, which could be bad if you have a larger data set. I have done that with a pseudo-Schwartzian transform. That also allows me to get rid of the splitting inside the subroutine.

Then I just add a check for whether or not the second column contains a number to the existing code, with parentheses to secure precedence issues.

As ikegami has mentioned, the simplest solution might be to just use `no warnings 'numeric'` inside the subroutine. Although this will sort non-numerical and `0` as the same value.

### Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print $_->[-1] for sort custom_sort(),
    map [ split(/\|/, $_),  $_ ], <DATA>;

sub custom_sort {
    return $a->[0] <=> $b->[0]     
        || ($a->[1] =~ /\d/ && $b->[1] =~ /\d/ &&
            $a->[1] <=> $b->[1])     #second column numeric compare
          # ^----------------- this
        || $a->[1] cmp $b->[1];    
}


__DATA__
128114529000000|10|0
1212835|A|0
128114529000000|1|0
1212835|G|0
128114529000000|3|0
1212835|T|0
128114529000000|2|0
1212835|H|0
128114529000000|9|0
```

### Output:

```
1212835|A|0
1212835|G|0
1212835|H|0
1212835|T|0
128114529000000|1|0
128114529000000|2|0
128114529000000|3|0
128114529000000|9|0
128114529000000|10|0
```

Comment: Added checks for both values.

Comment: The trick this solution relies on is that 0-9 lexically sorts before a-zA-Z on modern machines. This will give a different result on an EBCDIC machine, but who uses those anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

```
no warnings 'numeric';
```

The following handles negative numbers too:

```
sub custom_sort {
    my @a_cols = split( /\|/, $a );
    my @b_cols = split( /\|/, $b );

    my $a_cols_1_is_text = $a_cols[1] =~ /^-?\d+\z/ ? 0 : 1;
    my $b_cols_1_is_text = $b_cols[1] =~ /^-?\d+\z/ ? 0 : 1;

    return $a_cols[0] <=> $b_cols[0]
        || $a_cols_1_is_text <=> $b_cols_1_is_text
        || $a_cols_1_is_text ? $a_cols[1] cmp $b_cols[1] : $a_cols[1] <=> $b_cols[1];
}
```